# Import existing project to new project on android studio

Tags: android

I have a free app on google store. Now on different new project I would like to add new functionality to the project code and monetize it.So I created new project in android studio with different package/domain/name and imported my old project by New->Import Project.But they opened separate android studio windows.Here I confused. My expectation was that the code should come to my new project space.I would like to reuse my old project code as whole. What I should do?

Comment: When you open a project, the IDE prompts "new window" or "this window".

Comment: android studio is not asking me that. New->Import project->Browse my project->Click on Ok. It is opening on new window. The version is 2.3.2

Answer (score 0):

> My expectation was that the code should come to my new project space

Not quite.

In order to merge two gradle projects (call them `app` and `library`), do the following.

#### Project space

```
settings.gradle
build.gradle
app
  build.gradle
library
  build.gradle
```

#### settings.gradle

```
include :app, :library
```

#### app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':library')
}
```

Now, you should be able to import the classes from the "library" into your "app"